# javascript table cell selection

Tags: javascript

i want to achive excel sheet select functionality into my html table.

ie, selection of cells in the matrix format such as 1x1,2x2,3x3 etc,

please provide the sample code.

sorry couldn't upload the images...

```
---------
| 1 | 4 |
---------
| 2 | 3 |
---------
```

just open the excel sheet and select two cells in one column(as in fig. cell 1 and cell 2) and then move to cell on the right(cell 3), here automatically the upper cell gets selected (cell 4)... i need the same functionality

Comment: http://www.webappers.com/2010/01/25/create-a-ms-excel-style-spreadsheet-with-jquery-sheet/

Comment: Now you should be able to post the image..

Comment: @rsenna, you should post that as an answer so people can vote on it, and the asker can accept it. I think it may answer the question nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-jQuery UI solution I made:

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/rxT5z/10/

**JavaScript**:

```
$('table td').hover(function() {
    for (var x = 0; x <= $(this).index(); x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y <= $(this).parent().index(); y++) {
            $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(y).children().eq(x).addClass('selected');
        }
    }
}, function() {
    $('table td').removeClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**:

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
}

table tr td.selected {
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 255);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this solution is only visual, not the real selection changed (window.getSelection() is not affected)

Answer (score -1):

(By @pkaeding request)

You can use [jquery.sheet](http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet). Seems to be a good choice. There you'll find some demos too.